# How to bake smoke simulation by parts

Tags: smoke-simulation, baking

Is it possible to bake the simulations by parts. To start one day, and then continue another day.
Like evry day doing 100 frames or so?
I saw a tutorial about continuing particle baking, but it doesn't work with smoke baking.
When I press Bake All Dynamics to continue the simulation, it starts from begining.

Comment: Imho this is not possible. If you ran this on a vm (virtual machine), disk and memory, you could perhaps "freeze" the vm, and resume it later.